# How to set a slug for a route attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5, custom-attributes, slug

I have an action like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/books/{id:int:min(1)}/{slug?}")]
public ActionResult Book(int? id, string slug)
{
    if (slug == null)
    {
        slug = "awesome-book";
        return RedirectToAction("Book", new { id, slug });
    }

    etc.
}
```

The problem is that the new route is generated like '**books/1?slug=awesome-book**' and that's not what I wanted but '**books/1/awesome-book**'. How can I properly set the slug?

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem with generating route URLs. Since the `slug` route param is optional, the routing framework stops at `/books/1` and then tacks on any params not covered by the URL as a query string, which in this case includes `slug`. This is due to the short circuiting system the routing framework employs and there's really nothing you can do about it.

There is a workaround, though. If instead of using an optional param, you use another route, you can name that route and then reference it explicitly. For example:

```
[Route("~/books/{id:int:min(1)}", Order = 1)]
[Route("~/books/{id:int:min(1)}/{slug}", Order = 2, Name = "BookWithSlug")]
```

Then, you can generate the URL with:

```
return RedirectToRoute("BookWithSlug", new { id, slug });
```

And, you'll end up with the URL you want.

Comment: Yes, thank you, this does the job unfortunately if you have another route like "/books/1/pages" it will detect multiple routes because it cannot distinguish between a slug and the last segment from another route.

Comment: Technically, that was a problem even before, as if you tried to go to `/books/1/pages` you'd have two matching matching routes as well. Nevertheless, you can simply change your route param to `{slug:regex(^(?!pages)$)}`

Comment: Agree and thank you for the regex solution, yet it doesn't feel ok because if I have a book called "pages" I will get into trouble. I think I'll append a slug only to routes where I know will not have "subroutes" unless maybe you have a better idea (and have the id as well)?
I'm thinking about chaging the "subroutes" to /books/pages?bookId=1 although it's not that pretty.

Comment: Well, an alternative would be to forgo having both an id and a slug and just use one or the other. Then the ambiguity is removed as you'll either have `/books/1/pages` or `/books/some-awesome-book/pages`. Personally, I'd say just drop the id and use the slug to query your objects.